# Should I close ReadStream after using .pipe() method

Tags: node.js

I'm reading  file using `FS#createReadStream` method, then piping it to some writable streams using `#pipe()` method. Like this:

```
const stream = fs.createReadStream(...);
const transformedStream = imgStream.pipe(someTransformer).pipe(anotherTransfomer);
// do something with transformedStream
```

In docs of `#createReadStream()` method I found that [it has](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) `autoClose` parameter set by default to `true`.

And from other side, I found this [in documentation of `#pipe()` method](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options):

> One important caveat is that if the Readable stream emits an error
>   during processing, the Writable destination is not closed
>   automatically. If an error occurs, it will be necessary to manually
>   close each stream in order to prevent memory leaks.

So I have 2 questions:

1. Should I close readable and writable streams in Node JS at all? (Manually, using the `try-finally` block). Or streams closed automatically?
2. or  should I close streams only and only when I'm using `#pipe()` method? ( because `#pipe()` can result to memory leaks)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using the pipe event, then you can use unpipe to end it.

Below is an example of using pipe(), and unpipe() event.

```js
const writer = getWritableStreamSomehow();
const reader = getReadableStreamSomehow();
writer.on('unpipe', (src) => {
  console.error('Something has stopped piping into the writer.');
  assert.equal(src, reader);
});
reader.pipe(writer);
reader.unpipe(writer);
```

According to node.js [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_unpipe), The 'unpipe' event is emitted when the stream.unpipe() method is called on a Readable stream, removing this Writable from its set of destinations.

To specifically address your questions, here are my thoughts:

> 1) Should I close readable and writable streams in Node JS at all?
>   (Manually, using the try-finally block). Or streams closed
>   automatically?
>
> 2) or should I close streams only and only when I'm using #pipe()
>   method? ( because #pipe() can result to memory leaks)

You must close your stream(s) no matter you are using pipe() or not. (Also I disagree with your comment about memory leakage issue if using pipe() only )

Also you can't close your stream in a traditional javascript try() catch() finally() clause. Reason is because the read and write stream are being executed asynchronously. Instead you have to emit the end event for them.

example:

```js
var readStream = getReadableStreamSomehow();
readStream
    .on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log(chunk);
    })
    .on('end', function () {
        console.log('All the data in the file has been read');
    })
    .on('close', function (err) {
        console.log('Stream has been Closed');
    });
```

You can emit the same events for writable stream.

Comment: Thanks, I a bit edited my question to be more structured. Can you please give answers for both of my questions.

Comment: I had wrongly assumed that calling `unpipe` right after `pipe` would result in closing the pipe early, but it doesn't. Thanks!